# PHP Array to excel - Unwanted output

Tags: php, html, curl, output, export-to-excel

I need to generate an xls file from a PHP array. I know how I can achieve this: send the proper header and loop `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`. The problem is that I'm working in an environment that doesn't allow me to use ob_start(); and its derivated functions. I'm saying this because when I run this piece of code in the middle of a PHP script...

```
// Lot of unwanted output

// collecting data and defining $filename
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
// foreach stuff here

// Lot of unwanted output
```

... the resulting xls file contains also the output of the page. Basically I'm generating the xls right in the middle of a web page so you understand that in the xls I've the entire page with header, content and footer. I know that I should `curl();` to an external file with just my headers but the environment is hardcoded. I should re-establish the connection to database, include all required files, gain permissions (...) for this very small issue. In other words I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Said that my question is: is there a way to clear, flush, destroy (...) **everything** with the exception of my script that generates the xls? Keep in mind that I can't edit anything before and after my script.

Thank you.

Comment: It is somewhat ironic to generate a platform-specific file format in the middle of a platform-agnostic web page. Are you allowed to generate CSV instead?

Comment: use phpexcel library. or open a new tab in browser and output your file there.

Comment: Yes, I can generate CSV too but the problem would be the same.
About PHPExcel I don't want to install an entire library to achieve a simple task like generating a single xls file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve this issue with a POST to separate PHP file. I send all vaules serialized and with base64_decode. It works.